# Saving within a function in R

Tags: r, save

I've created this function in R, but the output that should be saved in a directory is not the expected.
When I print the i variable it has always the value 1, so the name of the files I'm saving are always the ones that I have on the first position of the vector.

```
function_filtering <- function(x){

upname <- c("up_toptable_alk.Rda", "up_toptable_kcbc1.Rda",   "up_toptable_kwt.Rda", "up_toptable_NaHog1.Rda", "up_toptable_Nawt.Rda","up_toptable_ox.Rda", "up_toptable_ter.Rda", "up_toptable_ypd.Rda")
downname <- c("down_toptable_alk.Rda", "down_toptable_kcbc1.Rda", "down_toptable_kwt.Rda", "down_toptable_NaHog1.Rda", "down_toptable_Nawt.Rda", "down_toptable_ox.Rda", "down_toptable_ter.Rda", "down_toptable_ypd.Rda")

p.value.cut <- which(x$P.Value < 0.05)
x <- x[p.value.cut,]    

up <- which(x$t > 0)
down <- which(x$t < 0)

up.p.value <- x[up,]
down.p.value <- x[down,]


save(up.p.value, file = upname[i])
save(down.p.value, file = downname[i])


i <- i + 1
print(i)

}

lapply(data, function_filtering)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you assign `i` originally in the function. Are you expecting there to be a different value of `i` for each object in `data`? If so, you might want to look into  `seq_along(data)` , and pass the data object to your function as another argument.

Comment: It should be At the begining og the función. I didnt put it here but its on the original code. i = 1

Comment: The problem is `i` is being changed only locally to the function `function_filtering`, so the assignment `i <- i + 1` doesn't affect the global value of `i`. To do global assignment, use `i <<- i + 1`; that said, this implementation is pretty clunky, and it might be a good idea to do this within a loop (e.g., something that loops through the values of a vector of `x` values) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example, I can't solve your exact problem. But I think this is what you are aiming for.

```
data <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') 
toy <- function(x, d) { 
    # x is the integer from seq_along
    # d is the data you want to subset
    paste(x, d[x], sep='_')
}
# Then use lapply to run the function on each element of data
# extra arguments can be passed in at the end 
lapply(seq_along(data), toy, d=data)
```

The output is

```
[[1]]
[1] "1_a"

[[2]]
[1] "2_b"

[[3]]
[1] "3_c"

[[4]]
[1] "4_d"
```